# Show that $\sum a_n < \sum b_n$ if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are non-negative convergent and $\forall n, a_n \leq b_n$ and $\exists k$ s.t. $a_k < b_k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing a question that says

> Suppose $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are convergent series of nonnegative numbers. Show that if $a_n\leq b_n$ for all n and if $a_n < b_n$ for at least one n, then $\sum a_n < \sum b_n$.

I'm thinking that:
Suppose $\sum a_n = A$ and $\sum b_n = B$, then
if we let $ps_n^{(a)}$ and $ps_n^{(b)}$ denote the partial sum of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$, then
$\sum b_n - \sum a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ps_n^{(a)} - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ps_n^{(b)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (ps_n^{(a)} - ps_n^{(b)}) = \sum (b_n - a_n) = B-A$.

However, I don't know how to show that B is larger than A. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Show the contrapositive. If you already know that $a_n \le b_n$ for all $n$, and you further assume that $a_n \not< b_n$ for all $n$ as well, what does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Using Comparison Test, it is quite straightforward: assume that $a_k<b_k$. Then, since $a_n\le b_n$ for each $n\in\{1,2,\dots, k-1\}$, we have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_n < \sum_{n=1}^k b_n 
$$

Now, since $a_n\le b_n$ for every $n> k$, the Comparison Test implies that we have $$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n \le \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty b_n$$

Adding both inequalities, we get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$.

(Note: I consider sequences whose indices start at $1$ for simplicity of notations)